# TypeError: <Response 36 bytes [200 OK]> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am writing web service using restful flask.
The below code giving me this error -  **TypeError:  is not JSON serializable**

```
from flask import jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource
class Recipe(Resource):
   def get(self):
      return jsonify({"status": "ok", "data": ""}), 200
```

How ever this code is working fine

```
from flask import jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource
class Recipe(Resource):
   def get(self):
      return jsonify({"status": "ok", "data": ""})
```

The Below code is also working

```
from flask import jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource
class Recipe(Resource):
def get(self):
   return {"status": "ok", "data": ""},200
```

I have noticed that I get the error when I use jsonify and response code together, I need to use jsonfy because I will be sending object as response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the solution - Flask has this function called **make_response**

```
from flask import jsonify, make_response

class Recipe(Resource):
   def get(self):
   return make_response(jsonify({"status": "ok", "data": ""}), 201)
```

Comment: How do U get this json out of the response on the client? Above returns `<Response 36 bytes [201 CREATED]>`. How can I get the dict out of that? ` i.e. `res['status'] => 'ok'` `json.loads(res)` fails

Comment: Found answer here - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#response-objects `res.data`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I realized that I made a small mistake when I was trying to convert the result of `jsonify` method to `str`.

```
str(jsonify({'code':200, 'message': 'test'}))
```